# Simple association mapping with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have two hibernate mapping files. I've tried several approaches to tie them using this [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html). Could you please show me simpliest way to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.Player" table="PLAYER">
        <id name="playerId" type="int" >
            <column name="ID" precision="5" scale="0"/>
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">PLAYER_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <!-- ... -->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And the second one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.AnnualFee" table="ANNUAL_FEE">
        <id name="id" type="int" >
            <column name="ID" precision="5" scale="0"/>
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="playerId" type="int">
            <column name="PLAYER_ID" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <!-- ... -->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I want them be associated by `playerId`and to be able to execute `outer join` further.

---

**Edited:**

I wanted to do it like this:

```
<id name="playerId" type="int" >
            <column name="ID" precision="5" scale="0"/>
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">PLAYER_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <set name="playerId" table="ANNUAL_FEE">
            <key column="PLAYER_ID"/>
            <one-to-many class="model.AnnualFee" />
        </set>
```

But idea then highlights `getPlayerId()` with:

> “more than one attribute configured for field 'getPlayerId'”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<many-to-one name="player" insert="false" update="false" class="model.Player" fetch="select">
    <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

And add to `AnnualFee` not just `int playerId` but object `Player`

```
public class AnnualFee {
    private int id;
    private Player player;
//...
```